# Python search and replace with search result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi there I have 2 excel files, where on one is a table with some names (col A, excel 1) and values and the other one contains a phylogenetic tree with all the data stored in 6 columns tab separated (excel 2).

Xlsx 1:

> g__Mannheimia
>   g__Peptococcus
>   g__unspecific_Proteobacteria 
>   ***g__Acinetobacter***

Xlsx 2 (6 columns):

> Row1:
>   d__Bacteria   p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  o__Enterobacterales f__Enterobacteriaceae   g__Salmonella   s__ 
>   Row2:
>   d__Bacteria   p__Firmicutes   c__Bacilli  o__Lactobacillales  f__Streptococcaceae g__Streptococcus   s__ 
>   Row3:
>   d__Bacteria   p__Actinobacteriota c__Actinobacteria   o__Mycobacteriales  f__Mycobacteriaceae g__Mycobacterium     s__ 
>   Row4:
>   d__Bacteria   p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  o__Enterobacterales f__Enterobacteriaceae   g__Klebsiella    s__ 
>   Row5:
>   d__Bacteria   p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  o__Pseudomonadales  f__Moraxellaceae    ***g__Acinetobacter***   s__

What I'm trying to do is, search each row of xlsx 2 for the names in xlsx 1, then if an exact match is found on any of the 6 columns, copy the whole row (6 columns in total) and replace the name (1 column, should also stay like that) in xlsx 1 with this data. This can be done by hand with the search and replace function, but because it's a huge amount of data I'm trying to find another way to do it.

I'm trying to solve this with the help of pandas and already tried some stuff. At the moment I'm stuck here, because I can't even find my matching data on the second xlsx.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

analysis_data_df = pd.read_excel('Mund_Biome_Raw_Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Genus', header=None, usecols='A', skiprows=3)
analysis_data = analysis_data_df.values.tolist()
# print(List1)
source_data_df = pd.read_excel('170519_taxonomy_in_qiime.xlsx', sheet_name='97_otu_taxonomy', header=None)
source_data = source_data_df.values.tolist()
# print(list_2)
matching = [s for s in source_data if any(xs in s for xs in analysis_data)]
print(matching)
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: Be more specific : if for one row in source_data (first Excel file) you have several rows containing it in analysis_data (second Excel file), what are you supposed to do ? Are you searching in the same row index every time ?

Comment: Edited my post to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an algorithm called suffix automaton and do the search efficiently (O(n) taking k on O(nlogk) as a constant being its the alphabets size), you can find more about this alg and its implementation here:
https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html

Because you are not making too complicated comparison, you could use a simpler and shorter algorithm like kmp which is O(T+P) being T the length of the larger string and P the pattern length to look for:
https://www.google.com.co/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/amp/

Or use regex, which is in python standard library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
This last approach can take up more time to compute, but its a simpler implementation

Cheers :)